# Managing MultiIndex Dataframe objects

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

So, yet another problem using grouped DataFrames that I am getting so confused over...

I have defined an aggregation dictionary as:

```
aggregations_level_1 = {
       'A': {
           'mean': 'mean',
        }, 

       'B': {
           'mean': 'mean',
        },  
    }
```

And now I have two grouped DataFrames that I have aggregated using the above, then joined:

```
grouped_top = 
     df1.groupby(['group_lvl']).agg(aggregations_level_1)
grouped_bottom = 
     df2.groupby(['group_lvl']).agg(aggregations_level_1)
```

Joining these:

```
df3 = grouped_top.join(grouped_bottom, how='left', lsuffix='_top_10', 
rsuffix='_low_10')

                      A_top_10        A_low_10     B_top_10        B_low_10
                      mean            mean         mean            mean
group_lvl                                      
    a                 3.711413    14.515901        3.711413        14.515901
    b                 4.024877    14.442106        3.694689        14.209040
    c                 3.694689    14.209040        4.024877        14.442106
```

Now, if I call index and columns I have:

```
print df3.index
    >> Index([u'a', u'b', u'c'], dtype='object', name=u'group_lvl')

print df3.columns
    >> MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A_top_10', u'A_low_10', u'B_top_10', u'B_low_10'], [u'mean']],
       labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

So, it looks as though I have a regular DataFrame-object with index `a,b,c` but each column is a MultiIndex-object. Is this a correct interpretation?

- How do I slice and call this? Say I would like to have only `A_top_10, A_low_10` for all `a,b,c`?
- Only `A_top_10, B_top_10` for `a` and `c`?

I am pretty confused so any overall help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers), but first sort columns by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) else error:

> UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (1), lexsort depth (0)'

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)

idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[:, idx[['A_low_10', 'A_top_10'], :]]
print (df1)
            A_low_10  A_top_10
                mean      mean
group_lvl                     
a          14.515901  3.711413
b          14.442106  4.024877
c          14.209040  3.694689
```

And:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df2 = df.loc[['a','c'], idx[['A_top_10', 'B_top_10'], :]]
print (df2)
           A_top_10  B_top_10
               mean      mean
group_lvl                    
a          3.711413  3.711413
c          3.694689  4.024877
```

EDIT:

> So, it looks as though I have a regular DataFrame-object with index a,b,c but each column is a MultiIndex-object. Is this a correct interpretation?

I think very close, better is say I have `MultiIndex` in `columns`.